# Is it possible to write files using NodeJS on a static website?

Tags: node.js, web, surge.sh

Or is it possible to host a NodeJS-based web app on a static website host, like [surge.sh](https://surge.sh)? Locally, I can start the node server in the console; is that something I can do on a static website host like Surge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general that is not possible.

You need at least the option, to get to the bash/console of the server, where you websites are getting hosted. Not only that you need to install node.js initially, you also need to start the node.js-webserver and in addition to that, you probably need even more flexibility e.g. to install several npm packets.

There might be static webhosters who can offer that via a control console or a GUI but personally I don't know a single one who can do that.